Can we bring secrets from databricks scope or key vault while deploying databricks asset bundles
I am trying to deploy a databricks asset bundle which deploy few databricks workflow jobs.
In the target environments, I am currently providing workspace host name and cluster id respectively.
I try to keep these details in a key vault and tried to fetch the same in the bundle deployments, but it is not working.
Is there any way that we can get the secrets from key vault or db secret scope for the bundle deployment?
Current Scenario:
prod:
    workspace:
      host: https://adb-hostname
      root_path: /Workspace/a/b/.bundle/${bundle.name}/${bundle.target}
    variables:
      DEST_CATALOG: "schema"  # Value for the 'DEST_CATALOG' parameter in prod
      workspace_host: ""
      job_compute_policy_id: ""

expected : once we define the variable in the bundle yml file, get these values from key vault or secret scope.
prod:
    workspace:
      host: $(var.workspace_host)
      root_path: /Workspace/a/b/.bundle/${bundle.name}/${bundle.target}
    variables:
      DEST_CATALOG: $(schema_name)  # Value for the 'DEST_CATALOG' parameter in prod
      workspace_host: "value from KV/scope"
      job_compute_policy_id: "value from KV/scope"

I am deploying these dab from azure cicd pipelines, where I call Azure Key Vault and Pass these required parameters while deploying the bundle as below.
 - task: AzureKeyVault@2
      displayName: Azure Key Vault
      inputs:
        azureSubscription: service-connection
        KeyVaultName: 'kv-name'
        SecretsFilter: '*'
        RunAsPreJob: true

# Validate bundle to be deployed to the staging workspace
    - script: |
        databricks bundle validate -t dev --var="workspace_host=$(db-workspace-host)" --var="job_compute_policy_id=$(db-compute-policy-id)"
      workingDirectory: $(workingDirectory)
      displayName: 'Validate bundle for development'
      env:
        ARM_CLIENT_SECRET: $(ARM_CLIENT_SECRET)

    # Deploy bundle to Development workspace
    - script: |
        databricks bundle deploy -t dev --var="workspace_host=$(db-workspace-host)" --var="job_compute_policy_id=$(db-compute-policy-id)"
      workingDirectory: $(workingDirectory)
      displayName: 'Deploy bundle to development'
      env:
        ARM_CLIENT_SECRET: $(ARM_CLIENT_SECRET)

But this is failing at validation throwing error for workspace host.
It seems like for validation it is expecting the url, so if we could connect to keyvault from the bundle yml file then we could check that possibility as well.
Error: failed during request visitor: default auth: cannot configure default credentials, please check https://docs.databricks.com/en/dev-tools/auth.html#databricks-client-unified-authentication to configure credentials for your preferred authentication method. 
Config: host=${var.workspace_host}, azure_client_secret=***, azure_client_id=***, azure_tenant_id=***. Env: ARM_CLIENT_SECRET, ARM_CLIENT_ID, ARM_TENANT_ID

Name: bundle_name
Target: dev
Workspace:
  Host: ${var.workspace_host}
  Path: /Workspace/a/b/.bundle/${bundle.name}/${bundle.target}

Appreciated any support. Thanks in Advance!
If you find this question simple or irrelevant, please still provide a straightforward solution while you proceed with devoting. This will be greatly appreciated and helpful.

have you tried any approach and facing blockers?

I have updated with the approach i tried.  Is there any way that we could call key vault from the databricks.yml file used for bundle configuration.

no option for key vault in bundle configuration check this mappings https://docs.databricks.com/en/dev-tools/bundles/settings.html#mappings

After you define variables in the bundle yaml file it checks the variables in following manner.


Within any  --var  options specified as part of the  bundle  command.
Within any environment variables set that begin with  BUNDLE_VAR_.
Within any  variables  mappings, among the  targets  mappings within your bundle configuration files.
Any  default  value for that variable’s definition, among the top-level  variables  mappings within your bundle configuration files.


So, inside the bundle yaml file you cannot retrieve the key vault secret.
Below are possible ways,
retrieve the key vault secrets and store it in environment variable prefixing BUNDLE_VAR_ like
BUNDLE_VAR_workspace_host and  BUNDLE_VAR_job_compute_policy_id
Retrieve secret using any one of the below command.
databricks secrets get-secret youscope your_secret

or
az keyvault secret show --vault-name <key-vault-name> --name <key-name>

and assign the value to above environment variables.
Next, when run validate or deploy bundle commands automatically takes these variables.
OR
You can pass the values in --var argument like below.
databricks bundle validate --var="workspace_host=<value_from_databricks_command>,job_compute_policy_id=<value_from_databricks_command>"

# Or:
databricks bundle validate --var="workspace_host=<value_from_databricks_command>" --var="job_compute_policy_id=<value_from_databricks_command>"

Add this step as bash script in you CI/CD pipeline and test using validate command.
You can check here for more information.

Tried the same but getting below error. seems like not able to read the host name passed as variable.

Error: failed during request visitor: default auth: cannot configure default credentials, please check https://docs.databricks.com/en/dev-tools/auth.html#databricks-client-unified-authentication to configure credentials for your preferred authentication method. Config: host=${var.workspace_host}, azure_client_secret=***, azure_client_id=***, azure_tenant_id=***. Env: ARM_CLIENT_SECRET, ARM_CLIENT_ID, ARM_TENANT_ID

Name: bundle_name
Target: dev
Workspace:
  Host: ${var.workspace_host}
  Path: /Workspace/a/b/.bundle/${bundle.name}/${bundle.target}


error related to default credentials. what you are trying? what is the authentication using for bundle validate?

service principle is used for authenticating.

you need to configure it properly in .databrickscfg profiles. refer this doc https://docs.databricks.com/en/dev-tools/auth/oauth-m2m.html#language-CLI

Before running assest bundle commands you should have configured authentication please do it

it is there, If I provide host name directly instead of parameterising it works fine.

Ok does job_compute_policy_id working while giving it in vars? Check by giving host name directly and job_compute_policy_id in vars.

Which method you using? setting BUNDLE_VAR_ or passing it in --var arguments

I tried it by passing --var arguments. Also I tried the BUNDLE_VAR method also but still getting the same error.

try setting BUNDLE_VAR_ like given in solution also try only job_compute_policy_id  through vars and host name directly.

passing --var arguments is working fine for other variables like compute_id and all others except for workspace host. BUNDLE_VAR should be defined in the databricks.yml file and pass value form KV as variable for bundle deployment in cicd yml?

no in ci cd itself you set the env variables  BUNDLE_VAR_workspace_host and BUNDLE_VAR_job_compute_policy_id like how set env:         ARM_CLIENT_SECRET: $(ARM_CLIENT_SECRET)

And how should we call it in the databricks.yml file ? Is it like  host: ${BUNDLE_VAR_workspace_host}

no it automatically takes variables starting with BUNDLE_VAR_ check here once https://docs.databricks.com/en/dev-tools/bundles/variables.html#set-a-variables-value
